# Problem with install newest version of rstudio in Ubuntu 16.04,

Tags: 16.04, ssl, rstudio

I have some issue with install R-Studio on Ubuntu 16.04 LTS. 
When I install `rstudio-1.0.44-amd64.deb` this version works.

I try:

```
sudo apt-get install gdebi-core
wget https://download2.rstudio.org/server/trusty/amd64/rstudio-server-1.2.5033-amd64.deb
sudo gdebi rstudio-server-1.2.5033-amd64.deb
```

result:

```
rstudio: error while loading shared libraries: libssl.so.1.1: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

Have you ever had the same problem?

Results:

```
/snap/core18/1668/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libssl.so.1.0.0
/snap/core18/1668/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libssl.so.1.1
/snap/core/8592/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libssl.so.1.0.0
/snap/core/8689/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libssl.so.1.0.0
/snap/spotify/36/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libssl.so.1.0.0
/snap/spotify/41/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libssl.so.1.1
find: ‘/run/user/1000/doc’: Permission denied
find: ‘/run/user/1000/gvfs’: Permission denied
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libssl.so.1.0.0
/usr/local/Wolfram/Mathematica/12.0/SystemFiles/Libraries/Linux-x86-64/libssl.so.1.0.0
/usr/local/Wolfram/Mathematica/12.0/SystemFiles/Components/WSMCore/SystemModeler/SystemFiles/Activation/Linux-x86-64/libssl.so.1.0.0
/usr/local/share/anki/bin/libssl.so.1.0.0
/home/mw/.Mathematica/Paclets/Repository/HTTPClient-10.1.33/LibraryResources/Linux-x86-64/libssl.so
/home/mw/.Mathematica/Paclets/Repository/HTTPClient-10.1.33/LibraryResources/Linux/libssl.so
```

and:

```
ldd /usr/lib/rstudio-server/bin/* | grep local ldd: /usr/lib/rstudio-server/bin/pandoc: not regular file ldd: /usr/lib/rstudio-server/bin/postback: not regular file
```

and:

```
N: Couldn't find any package by glob 'rstudio-1.0.143-amd64.deb'
N: Couldn't find any package by glob 'rstudio-1.0.44-amd64.deb'
N: Couldn't find any package by glob 'rstudio-1.2.1335-amd64.deb'
N: Couldn't find any package by glob 'rstudio-1.2.5033-amd64.deb'
N: Couldn't find any package by glob 'rstudio-server-1.2.1335-amd64.deb'
```

Comment: libssl.so.1.1 is missing. Suggest you install it.

Comment: I can't reproduce the issue with `sudo apt-get install r-base-core` and all exactly same commands as you wrote above on clean Ubuntu 16.04 LTS VM. What is your Ubuntu version? Can you access the `http://op_of_server:8787/` from web-browser? How did you get `rstudio` executable installed from `rstudio-server` package?

Comment: @N0rbert:
Description: Ubuntu 16.04.6 LTS
Release: 16.04
Codename: xenial

Comment: @N0rbert I tried: /usr/lib/rstudio-server/bin/rserver: error while loading shared libraries: libssl.so.1.1: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

Comment: Please add output of `sudo find / -type f -name libssl.so*` with `ldd /usr/lib/rstudio-server/bin/* | grep local` and `apt-cache policy rstudio*` and please note that `rstudio-server` on my clean 16.04 LTS VM it is linked to */lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libssl.so.1.0.0*, so you have some garbage in your system, or messed rstudio/rstudio-server installations.

Comment: I tried: sudo ln -s /snap/core18/1668/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcrypto.so.1.1 /usr/lib/libcrypto.so.1.1

Comment: sudo ln -s /snap/core18/1668/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libssl.so.1.1 /usr/lib/libssl.so.1.1

Comment: the result:/usr/lib/rstudio-server/bin/rserver: /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6: version `GLIBC_2.25' not found (required by /usr/lib/libcrypto.so.1.1)